# Understanding Extraneous File Extensions

Tags: javascript, file-extension

I've frequently seen JavaScript files with an extra file extension (I *think* "extension" is the proper term; if not, someone correct me because I've failed to find a resource that labels them) such as:

```
someFile.bundle.js
         ^^^^^^
```

I remember reading that adding file extensions like that can be used a naming convention (`.bundle` would refer to a file that *bundles* a collection of other files).

I've recently seen more file extensions such as:

```
someFile.spec.js
         ^^^^
```

and now I'm questioning the behavior behind these extensions; are they just used for convention? Are the names of these types of extensions arbitrary (as in someone can put any old extension there and it wouldn't affect anything)? When should these be used? Are there certain extensions that you *should* use (and maybe some your *shouldn't*)?

Comment: filenames are irrelevant on the web. you could use `.arglebargle` as the extension for your JS files. what matters is the mimetype the webserver sends out along with the file's contents when it's requested, e.g. `<script src="somejsfile.hi_mom" type="text/js">` is just as valid as `src="somejsfile.js"`. some particular JS library may use extra filename components as part of its scheme, but there's nothing in JS or HTML that says you can/can't do that.

Comment: I think `.arglebargle` was an old CompuServe format, no?

Comment: @MarcB I didn't know that - really interesting!

Comment: @MarcB is quite right that the name of the script file is completely meaningless to the browser. Your *server* may use the name (specifically the extension) to determine what MIME type to send back with it when requested. (Side note: The `type="text/js"` in @MarcB's example is invalid and likely to make the browser skip the script [if it [follows the rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type)].. Best to leave `type` off entirely if the script is JavaScript, and (separately) to ensure that your server sends the correct MIME type with the script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't extensions, really. A file extension is (at least typically) the *last* `.` though the end of the filename. Those are just `.js` files. The rest is purely the name.

People do this to categorize things. For instance, in your example, I suspect the first file is generated automatically based on several input files; e.g., it's a *bundle*. The second probably contains test code, to ensure that something's external API works correctly. In both cases I'm speculating, but the point is that it's just a naming convention. It could be `someFile-bundle.js` and `someFile-spec.js` just as easily.

For a while I used the convention `somefile.es6.js` to indicate that a file contained ES2015 (ES6) syntax and needed transpiling before being used on the web, but a client of mine does the same thing with `somefile-es6.js` (which I think is more common than mine). This makes it easy to pick them out in build scripts and such (either the `.es6.js` or `-es6.js`).

Comment: So the file names can have periods and it's completely valid / doesn't affect the file? And the names can simply be arbitrary to help organization?

Comment: @NickZuber: Yup. Just like you can have (say) `2016.budget.xlsx`. It's still an Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from just javascript files, filename extensions can be used for all kinds of processing directives. For instance, I have taken to naming many of my php files like `file.ajax.php` or `file.process.php` that include common header files that contain logic that check the filename extensions to determine whether or not to serve up html, such as common navs.

I'm also reminded of [Laravel's blade templating engine](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) that uses the `.blade.php` "file extension", as it's syntax contains operations above and beyond normal php.